# Тема на Magento

Tags: html, css, cms, magento

Как перенести верстку на Magento?То есть сделать свою тему

Comment: Уточните, в чем именно вы видите проблему? Вообще не знаете с чего начать? Попытайтесь выделить конкретный участок из плана решения задачи, который вызывает затруднение.

Comment: ну,мне тут посоветовали отталкиваться от базовой темы.типа смотри - повторяй как там - меняй под себя.

Answer (score 1):

Руководствуясь [документацией](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-general.html) на официальном сайте

Comment: а случайно нету на русском?

Comment: есть что-то подобное: http://magento-forum.ru/topic/629/

Comment: @VenZell натыкался вчера.много полезностей, но,увы,не то, на что рассчитывал.спасибо